# I've relocated user profiles but something keeps creating new 'documents' folders on the old server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I have been moving user profiles from one server to another.  For the question we'll call them 'oldserver' and 'newserver' and the user is 'jbloggs'

While the user is logged out...

Copy the entire profile of jbloggs (`\\oldserver\users\jbloggs`) to the new server using robocopy.

When that is complete, rename the old folder to 'moved_jbloggs'

Then go into active directory and change the 'Profile path' to `\\\newserver\users\jbloggs\profile` and 'Home folder' 'Connect U:' to `\\newserver\users\jbloggs`

I have also changed the group policy 'redirect my documents' setting from `\\oldserver\users` to `\\newserver\users`

But when jbloggs logs in,  a new folder is created in oldserver!  `\\oldserver\users\jbloggs\jbloggs's documents`

Does anyone know what could cause the user folder to be re-created on the old server?  Is there a further step that needs to be taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had what looks like a slightly similar issue when we migrated user profiles to new hardware. Our "It's on fire and needs a fix" solution was to blow away the local profile on the machines that were logging in.

---

The other fix that we employed with some of our more difficult users was to open the registry and search for `oldserver` and change relevant keys to point to the proper location. Consider repeating the search with `users\jbloggs\jbloggs's documents`

As a *nix admin the explanation I made up and have no backing support for was: Windows is doing something silly with the cached profile. Blowing it away caused it to be rebuilt in a more proper manor.

Comment: On a windows XP machine, I tried renaming one of the users folders while they are logged out.  c:\documents and settings\jbloggs to c:\documents and settings\jblogs_old.  When logging in it does recreate the profile,  but then it goes and creates the new folder again in oldserver!    The odd thing is, it doesn't call it 'My Documents' it calls it 'jbloggs's documents'.

Frustrating.  I'm going to try the rsop thing next.

Comment: @MrVimes - It calls the folder "My Documents" but you're seeing it called "jbloggs's Documents" because the folder contains a "desktop.ini" file and the Explorer shell is using the instructions in that file to obscure the folder name. If you use a command-prompt and do a `dir` in that location you'll see the folder *is* actually called "My Documents". Thanks, Explorer... stupid feature.

Comment: Thanke Evan.

I'm marking this (@lVlint67) answer as accepted, as I did manage to get one computer to pick up the GPO policy after I manually edited the registy.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a Group Policy Object (GPO) with the [Folder Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786749(v=ws.10).aspx) for the Documents folder enabled. Run a Resultant Set of Policy against a user with whom you are seeing the problematic behavior and it will lead you in the direction of the GPO you need to modify.

In the RSoP have a look in the "Windows Settings" sub-node of the "User Configuration" sub-node. I suspect you'll find a Folder Redirection policy there applying to the "Documents" folder. Assuming you do, before you go modifying it you would do well to read-up on how the feature works so that you have a good idea of what's going to happen when you change it.

Edit:

In my haste I neglected to see that you say you did modify a GPO containing some Folder Redirection settings. Check the event logs on clients that are exhibiting problems to verify that the Folder Redirection Client Side Extension (CSE) isn't logging any errors. It may be that your modified GPO is having a problem applying and the setting is remaining as it was. The CSE's Event Log messages should give you some indication if the modified GPO is failing to apply.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I changed the GPO.  But I will try the rsp anyway and see what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry-- in my haste I must have read right over that. Definitely check the Resultant Set of Policy-- it may also be that your updated GPO isn't applying properly to the client(s). I dropped on an edit about it.

Comment: I've had a chance to run rsop on a windows xp machine and it is showing the old server in folder redirection.  I ran it on my own windows 7 machine and it shows the updated folder redirection value.  I will now have a look in the event log to see if I can find anything.